# find out the biggest valu element by every title

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
    title = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "B", "C", "D", "D"),
    rate = c(100, 100, 100, 95, 92, 90, 90),
    name = c("G", "N", "E", "T", "O", "W", "L"),
    pos = c(10, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4)

)

  title  rate name    pos
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
  AA      100 G        10
  AA      100 N         1
  AA      100 E         2
  B        95 T         2
  C        92 O         3
  D        90 W         5
  D        90 L         4
```

I want to find out at every `title` which `name` has the biggest `pos` value.

So, for title AA, it would be G,  for title B, it would be T, for title C it would be O and for title D it would be W.

Comment: It's a dup but not with the linked by @kath, try `df1 %>% group_by(title) %>% summarise(mn=name[which.max(pos)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For B it should be "T"?

```
df1 %>% group_by(title) %>% top_n(1,pos) %>% pull(name)
```

Comment: Thanks!yes, for B is T.